# How do I configure flask_migrate to check only the models present

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have tested this and it works but takes more than 3 to 4 minutes time.
I am using python 2.7 and flask-migrate version is 2.2.1

```
def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if type_ == 'table':
        if re.search(r'^agent\_[a-z0-9\-]+\_home', name) is not None:
            return False
    return True



context.configure(connection=connection,
                      target_metadata=target_metadata,
                      include_object=include_object,
                      process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
                      **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args)
```

But flask-migrate is actually looping through out all the tables. 
I have more than 13000 tables and can increase dynamically from time to time, So the total migration takes a lot of time.

What I want is modify the migrations and just to check a given list of tables or only the models present.

Advance thanks if anyone will be able to help me out with this.

Comment: Just wanted to alert you that Flask-Migrate is just a simple wrapper for Alembic. Your question is really about Alembic, not Flask-Migrate.

Comment: yes. that I know. But i solved it putting dynamic tables under a new schema.
and ignoring some custom tables with the help of regex.